# NHibernate selecting from a many to many collection

Tags: nhibernate

I would like NHibernate to generate the following SQL but I'm stuggling with the code below

```
   SELECT rt.Id 
   FROM ClientContact cc  
     JOIN ClientContact_DefaultRequest d on d.ClientContactID = cc.Id
     JOIN RequestType rt on d.RequestTypeId = rt.Id
   WHERE 
     cc.Id = ContactId



public class GetDefaultRequestsForContact : SimpleQuery<IEnumerable<RequestType>>, IGetDefaultRequestsForContact
{
    public int ContactId { private get; set; }

    public GetDefaultRequestsForContact(ISession session) : base(session) { }

    public override IEnumerable<RequestType> Execute()
    {
        var x = Session.QueryOver<ClientContact>()
            .Where(c => c.Id == ContactId)
            .JoinQueryOver<RequestType>(c => c.DefaultRequests)
            .Select(c => c.DefaultRequests)
            .List();
        return null;
    }
}
```

The generated SQL is only selecting the parent id (which is the parameter) I want all the child Ids.

```
SELECT this_.Id as y0_
FROM   ClientContact this_
       inner join ClientContact_DefaultRequest defaultreq3_
         on this_.Id = defaultreq3_.ClientContactID
       inner join RequestType requesttyp1_
         on defaultreq3_.RequestTypeID = requesttyp1_.Id
WHERE  this_.Id = 313706 /* @p0 */
```

This works but it is not strongly typed (HQL).

```
        var x = Session.CreateQuery("SELECT R.Id FROM ClientContact cc JOIN cc.DefaultRequests R WHERE cc.Id = :contactId")
            .SetParameter("contactId",ContactId)
            .List<int>();
        return x;
```

Comment: HQL *IS* strongly typed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Aliases like:

```
ClientContact Cont = null;
RequestType Req = null;

var x = session.QueryOver<ClientContact>(() => Cont)
.Where(() => Cont.ID == ContactId)
.JoinAlias(() => Cont.DefaultRequests, ()=> Req, JoinType.LeftOuterJoin)
.Select(ignore => Req.Id) // <-- Select wants a parameter
.List<int>();
```

Comment: Hi there seems to be a problem with the Select(() => Req.Id). It wants a ClientContact. Any ideas how to project into the collection of RequestTypes?

Comment: I added an HQL version to the post. It works, but I really would like to know how to do this strongly typed.

Comment: @CRG I suggested an edit to Faber's answer. Until it is accepted, use `.Select(ignore => Req.Id).List<int>();` I tested that and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You have to turn it around.</strike> I believe Faber's answer will also work well. So you do not have to turn it around. (But you could.)

```
ClientContact cAlias = null;

var x = Session.QueryOver<RequestType>()
    .JoinAlias(rt => rt.ClientContacts, () => cAlias)
    .Where(() => cAlias.Id == ContactId)
    .Select(rt => rt.Id) // not sure what you want returned here, Id or the object)
    .List();
```

Comment: Hi, I can't navigate from RequestType to ClientContacts. I'm only after the Ids at this stage.

Comment: @CRG Then Faber's answer will probably give you the desired result.